# How can I print specific informations from an sql row for a given input?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my sql query:

```
$sql = "SELECT username, password, am, email, age, sex, country, city FROM personal_details where username='username_' and password='$password_'";
```

The variables $username_ and $password_ are taken from an HTML Form. What I want to do is to print all the informations(username, password, am, email, age, sex, country, city) for these values and if nothing exists print "There are no records for the given input".

Full Code:

```
$username_ = $_POST["username"];
$password_ = $_POST["password"];

mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");

$sql = "SELECT username, password, am, email, age, sex, country, city FROM personal_details WHERE username='username_' AND password='$password_'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (!$result) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
    exit;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["username"];
    echo $row["password"];
}


mysqli_close($conn);
```

And the error I am getting:

> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects
>   parameter 1 to be resource, object given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\register\view.php on line 27 No rows found, nothing to
>   print so am exiting

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php read the first Example and try something out ;) And use http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php  to check for rsutls, if is 0 then `"There are no records for the given input"`.  Only answer you get here. We help on code issues, we are not coding for you.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I edited the code according to the php document but still I am getting "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting". Any ideas?

Comment: Did you see the typo in the sql? Thing you are missing one `$` before `username_`  here: `WHERE username='username_' AND password='$password_'`.  :)